# Weird behavior of angular-google-maps in Safari

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Im using this project (http://angular-google-maps.org/#!/) to work with AngularJS. My code seems like:

**app.js**

```
function ( $scope, markerService ) {
    var markerCollection = [];

    angular.extend($scope, {
      map: {
        control: {},
        center: {
          latitude: 33.5,
          longitude: -112
        },
        zoom: 10,
        fit: true,
        visible: true,
        pan: true,
        options: {
          navigationControl: true,
          scaleControl: true
        }
      }
    });


        var setMapMarkers = function (){
      var markers = {};
      var index = 0;
      angular.forEach($scope.services, function (key) {
        var service = key.address;
        markerCollection.push(service);
        var serviceId = service.service.id;
        markers[index] = {
          "latitude": parseFloat(service.latitude),
          "longitude": parseFloat(service.longitude)
        };
        index++;
      });
      $scope.markers = markers;
    };
    setMapMarkers();    

 }
```

Im getting this behavior in Safari and its a very weird.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7iwlr9mnboem1d/MapGrab.mov?dl=0

Someone maybe know what can be the problem?